# My class=float is not floating within the code, and the whole html does not appear on the site via Google Tagmanager

Tags: html, css

I have copied and paste the following code and I want to apply this to my website. It should float at the right bottom.

I'm just a noob, I haven't tried anything, since I just don't know.

```
<div class="float" />
    <div class="dot" />
    <div class="at-about-fab">
        <div class="at-about-fab__thumbnail">
            <img alt="verkoper" src="https://d2tyltutevw8th.cloudfront.net/media/image/trump-round-1500174198.jpg" />
        </div>

        <div class="at-about-fab__meta">
            <h2>Call us now!</h2>
            <p><a href="tel:1234566">12345567890</a></p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
.float{
    position:fixed;
    width:290px;
    height:100px;
    bottom:14px;
    right:10px;
    background-color:4d4d4d;
    opacity: 0.1;
    border-radius:50px;
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 3px #999;
    opacity=50;
}

.dot {
    position: absolute;
    right: 215px;
    display:block;
    z-index:1000000;
    bottom: 30px;
    height: 35px;
    width: 35px;
    background-color: #bbb;
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 14px;
    height: 14px;
    background: #228B22;
    -webkit-transition:opacity 0.2s ease;
    -moz-transition:opacity 0.2s ease;
    -o-transition:opacity 0.2s ease;
}

.dot:hover{
    // Red(0-255), Blue(0-255), Green(0-255), Alpha (0-1)
    background-color:rgba(100,100,100,0); 
    opacity:0;
}

.at-about-fab {
    z-index: 999999;
    position: fixed;
    right: 40px;
    bottom: 40px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    flex-direction: row;
}

.at-about-fab:hover .at-about-fab__meta {
    opacity: 1;
}

.at-about-fab__thumbnail {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: -88px;
    background: #FFFFFF;
    width: 78px;
    height: 78px;
    border: 4px solid #EEEEEE;
    border-radius: 100%;
    padding: 1px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    overflow: show;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.at-about-fab__thumbnail img {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    border-radius: 100%;
}

.at-about-fab__meta {
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    opacity: 1;
    transition: 0.2s ease;
}

.at-about-fab__meta h2,
.at-about-fab__meta p {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.at-about-fab__meta h2 {
    color: #444444;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: 500;
}

.at-about-fab__meta p {
    color: #1a9228;
    font-size: 24px;
    font-weight: 300;
}

.at-about-fab__meta a {
    color: inherit;
    font-weight: 700;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

I want just everything floating at the right corner, i cannot seperate css and html since its going via tag manager.

By the way, I also please want to blur the background of the `class=float`, but do not know how.

Can someone help me?

Comment: I also included the blur effect in my updated answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I checked your code and there were a few typos. First there is a `</div>` too much. And in your css you use opacity, change the `=` to `:`. Also the dot `position` has to be `fixed` and not `absolute`. And for the blur you can add this `backdrop-filter: blur(10px);`

```css
.float{
    position:fixed;
    width:290px;
    height:100px;
    bottom:14px;
    right:10px;
    background-color:4d4d4d;
    opacity: 0.1;
    border-radius:50px;
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 3px #999;
    opacity:50;
    backdrop-filter: blur(10px);
  }
  .dot {
   position: fixed;
    right: 215px;
  display:block;
  z-index:1000000;
    bottom: 30px;
  height: 35px;
  width: 35px;
  background-color: #bbb;
  border-radius: 50%;
    width: 14px;
  height: 14px;
    background: #228B22;
  -webkit-transition:opacity 0.2s ease;
    -moz-transition:opacity 0.2s ease;
    -o-transition:opacity 0.2s ease;
}
  .dot:hover{
    background-color:rgba(100,100,100,0); 
    opacity:0;
}
  .at-about-fab {
  z-index: 999999;
  position: fixed;
  right: 40px;
  bottom: 40px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: row;
}
.at-about-fab:hover .at-about-fab__meta {
  opacity: 1;
}
.at-about-fab__thumbnail {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: -88px;
  background: #FFFFFF;
  width: 78px;
  height: 78px;
  border: 4px solid #EEEEEE;
  border-radius: 100%;
  padding: 1px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
          transform: translateY(-50%);
  overflow: show;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.at-about-fab__thumbnail img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 100%;
}
.at-about-fab__meta {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  opacity: 1;
  transition: 0.2s ease;
}
.at-about-fab__meta h2,
.at-about-fab__meta p {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.at-about-fab__meta h2 {
  color: #444444;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 500;
}
.at-about-fab__meta p {
  color: #1a9228;
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: 300;
}
.at-about-fab__meta a {
  color: inherit;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo. Nullam dictum felis eu pede mollis pretium. Integer tincidunt. Cras dapibus. Vivamus elementum semper nisi. Aenean vulputate eleifend tellus. Aenean leo ligula, porttitor eu, consequat vitae, eleifend ac, enim. Aliquam lorem ante, dapibus in, viverra quis, feugiat a, tellus. Phasellus viverra nulla ut metus varius laoreet. Quisque rutrum. Aenean imperdiet. Etiam ultricies nisi vel augue. Curabitur ullamcorper ultricies nisi. Nam eget dui.

Etiam rhoncus. Maecenas tempus, tellus eget condimentum rhoncus, sem quam semper libero, sit amet adipiscing sem neque sed ipsum. Nam quam nunc, blandit vel, luctus pulvinar, hendrerit id, lorem. Maecenas nec odio et ante tincidunt tempus. Donec vitae sapien ut libero venenatis faucibus. Nullam quis ante. Etiam sit amet orci eget eros faucibus tincidunt. Duis leo. Sed fringilla mauris sit amet nibh. Donec sodales sagittis magna. Sed consequat, leo eget bibendum sodales, augue velit cursus nunc, quis gravida magna mi a libero. Fusce vulputate eleifend sapien. Vestibulum purus quam, scelerisque ut, mollis sed, nonummy id, metus. Nullam accumsan lorem in dui. Cras ultricies mi eu turpis hendrerit fringilla. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; In ac dui quis mi consectetuer lacinia.

Nam pretium turpis et arcu. Duis arcu tortor, suscipit eget, imperdiet nec, imperdiet iaculis, ipsum. Sed aliquam ultrices mauris. Integer ante arcu, accumsan a, consectetuer eget, posuere ut, mauris. Praesent adipiscing. Phasellus ullamcorper ipsum rutrum nunc. Nunc nonummy metus. Vestibulum volutpat pretium libero. Cras id dui. Aenean ut eros et nisl sagittis vestibulum. Nullam nulla eros, ultricies sit amet, nonummy id, imperdiet feugiat, pede. Sed lectus. Donec mollis hendrerit risus. Phasellus nec sem in justo pellentesque facilisis. Etiam imperdiet imperdiet orci. Nunc nec neque. Phasellus leo dolor, tempus non, auctor et, hendrerit quis, nisi.

Curabitur ligula sapien, tincidunt non, euismod vitae, posuere imperdiet, leo. Maecenas malesuada. Praesent congue erat at massa. Sed cursus turpis vitae tortor. Donec posuere vulputate arcu. Phasellus accumsan cursus velit. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Sed aliquam, nisi quis porttitor congue, elit erat euismod orci, ac placerat dolor lectus quis orci. Phasellus consectetuer vestibulum elit. Aenean tellus metus, bibendum sed, posuere ac, mattis non, nunc. Vestibulum fringilla pede sit amet augue. In turpis. Pellentesque posuere. Praesent turpis.

Aenean posuere, tortor sed cursus feugiat, nunc augue blandit nunc, eu sollicitudin urna dolor sagittis lacus. Donec elit libero, sodales nec, volutpat a, suscipit non, turpis. Nullam sagittis. Suspendisse pulvinar, augue ac venenatis condimentum, sem libero volutpat nibh, nec pellentesque velit pede quis nunc. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Fusce id purus. Ut varius tincidunt libero. Phasellus dolor. Maecenas vestibulum mollis diam. Pellentesque ut neque. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas.

In dui magna, posuere eget, vestibulum et, tempor auctor, justo. In ac felis quis tortor malesuada pretium. Pellentesque auctor neque nec urna. Proin sapien ipsum, porta a, auctor quis, euismod ut, mi. Aenean viverra rhoncus pede. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Ut non enim eleifend felis pretium feugiat. Vivamus quis mi. Phasellus a est. Phasellus magna.
<div     class="float">
</div>
<div class="dot"></div>
<div class="at-about-fab">
  <div class="at-about-fab__thumbnail">
    <img alt="verkoper" src="https://d2tyltutevw8th.cloudfront.net/media/image/trump-round-1500174198.jpg" />
  </div>

  <div class="at-about-fab__meta">
    <h2>Call us now!</h2>
    <p><a href="tel:1234566">12345567890</a></p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Wauw, this is so good! haha! :-) Almost exactly how I wanted it. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Still, do you maybe know how to get the background a little vague / blurred? So the text is still readable on white background / dark background?

Comment: @rick you mean the whole background? Or do you want it like my edit?

Comment: @Rick if you want it less blurred change the `px` to 1 or 2 the it's readable

Comment: Thanks!! only thing is the background color, that one is not working at mines at the moment... Is that correct?

Comment: @Rick what background color?

Comment: @Rick the whole background?

Comment: I want the grey text pop out on a white blurred background of that vertical element

Comment: hahaha, ah oke. ehm, nou in de html tester laat ie dit zien: https://gyazo.com/6b30feffb5e4cae203dd775b75898d72 ----- maar via tagmanager zie ik a) dat grijze gebied niet, en ten tweede is de blur weg.. identieke code...

Comment: @Rick ik weet niet precies waar dit aan ligt het zou kunnen liggen aan de browser

Comment: oh wacht, wanneer ik de blur weghaal, heeft hij helemaal geen achtergrond... gaat het daar ergens in mis? 

.float{
    position:fixed;
    width:290px;
    height:100px;
    bottom:14px;
    right:10px;
    background-color:DADADA;
    opacity: 0.9;
    border-radius:20px;

  }

Comment: @Rick volgens mij moet je je background color met een rgba code instellen dan doet ie het wel kijk [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xzaor348/2/)

Comment: yess! nice! thanks!! haha! :-) laatste vraag, als dat mag: dat blok met die blur die verdwijnt onder sommige elementen op de website, zie deze GIF. is dat nog op te lossen? https://gyazo.com/bb0475f7c3124bb9262ecad596fece62

Comment: het lijkt in 'botsing' te zijn met de andere elementen op de website. is er nog een mogelijkheid om dit ding in het geheel boven alles te plaatsen?

Answer (score 0):

Hello @Rick float is the property of the class, not a class. Use following style.

```
  .your_class_name
  {
    float: right;  /* Left or right depends on your design */
  }
```

Comment: Using `float: right;` is a bad practice nowadays. Please consider newer techniques that are widely supported.

Comment: Hello @Roy , thanks for the suggestion :) , I will definitely try to do best.